# Why use null conditional operator when a variable that can't be null?

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator

I saw the below code from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose):

```cs
using System;

public sealed class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = new Bar();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _bar?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it needs to use `_bar?.Dispose();` instead of `_bar.Dispose();`?

`_bar` has been declared `readonly` and initialized in the constructor, so `_bar` will not be null and cannot be reassigned to `null`, then why do we need to do the null check on `_bar`?

Comment: You're right, it's pointless in this case.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case it's redundant. However, a slightly more complex constructor may allow `this` to escape<sup>1</sup> before invoking the `Bar` constructor and, of course, the `Bar` constructor could then `throw`, leaving the field unassigned.

If `Dispose` were then to be invoked on this partially constructed `Foo`, it would be `null`. This is slightly contrived but, there again, you're not expected to just literally have a `Foo` class that just wraps a `Bar` and does nothing else.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which you're also not doing ideally but it's valid to do so, however ill-judged it may be. This is required so that *something* is capable of calling the `Dispose` method on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for cleaner code. Just make the null checks in all you Dispose().

But technically, yes actually it's not an requirement.